# Iterating through JSON in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, loops

I'm working on a script that will list files on a site and, using the JSON response, download them and then delete them (not included in the code below).  The code I've pasted below allows me to list the files in the workspace, and then download them.  The problem I'm having is that it's overwriting the files.

For example, I have two files on the site I'm downloading from - File1.zip and File2.zip.  File1 contains a text file that says HI and File2 contains a text file that says BYE.  After running the below code, two files are downloaded, named File1.zip and File2.zip, but they both contain the contents of File2.zip.  If I change the below code so that $outFilePath is "C:\CRFDontDelete$id - $name", then 4 files are downloaded, the 1st two contain the contents of File1.zip and the other two contain the contents of File2.zip.

Not included are other parts of the script where I initialize and setup some of the signature requirements.  It's not relevant because that part is working fine.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and/or what I could be doing differently so that I download both files correctly?  FYI, after I download the files, I need to delete them so the next time files are there, they will have different ID's and names (it's for an automated process I'm working on).

```
#region Retrieve File List

$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$fileUnixTimestamp = [System.Math]::Truncate((Get-Date -Date $DateTime -UFormat %s))
#$fileUnixTimestamp = [System.Math]::Truncate((Get-Date -Date((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat %s))
$fileBaseURL = "https://upload.filegenius.com/api/file_list?api_key=" + $apiKey + "&path=" + $path + "&timestamp=" + $fileUnixTimestamp
$fileMessageSignature = [System.Bitconverter]::ToString($hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($fileBaseURL.ToString()))).Replace("-", [System.String]::Empty).ToLower()
$fileSignedURL = $fileBaseURL + "&signature=" + $fileMessageSignature
#[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$fileGetResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $fileSignedURL -Method GET
#$fileInfo = (($fileGetResponse.fileList.id | ConvertTo-Json) | ConvertFrom-Json) -Depth 5
$fileInfo = $fileGetResponse.fileList.files.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
$fileNames = $fileGetResponse.fileList.files.name | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
#write-host "######################################################################################################################"
write-host $fileInfo
#endregion

# Now we've listed all of the files, we need to loop through and download them by ID
$fileIDs = $fileInfo | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host $fileIDs #Output shows: 35011794 35009511     
$fileName = $fileNames | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host $fileName #Output shows:  File1.zip File2.zip   

#region Download Files
#$fileidnum = $fileGetResponse.filesList.files.id
foreach($id in $fileIDs)
{
    write-host $id
    write-host "------------"
    $testID = "35011794"
    $downloadUnixTimestamp = [System.Math]::Truncate((Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat %s))
    $downloadBaseURL = "https://upload.filegenius.com/api/file_download?api_key=" + $apiKey + "&file_id=" + $id + "&timestamp=" + $downloadUnixTimestamp
    $downloadSignature = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($downloadBaseURL.ToString()))).Replace("-", [System.String]::Empty).ToLower()
    $downloadSignedURL = $downloadBaseURL + "&signature=" + $downloadSignature
    
    
    #write-host "######################################################################################################################"
    #write-host $downloadSignedURL
    #write-host "######################################################################################################################"
    foreach($name in $fileName)
    {
        $outFilePath = "C:\CRFDontDelete\$name"
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        $fileDownload = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $downloadSignedURL -Method 'Get' -Outfile $outFilePath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after tinkering with it I figured it out.  I set a variable named $fileIDName and set it equal to $fileName[x] and outside of the 1st for each, I set x to 0 and then after the file is downloaded, I add 1 to x.  It's now correctly iterating through and pulling the relevant file ID and file name and downloading them.

Comment: I suggest you delete this post

Answer (score -2):

You're looping through both filenames for each input id.
It looks like the results from the second input id overwrite the first.

Here's your code summarised-

```
foreach($id in $fileIDs)
{
    #create url and signature here
    foreach($name in $fileName) #Download to both paths using the one URL created earlier
    {
        $outFilePath = "C:\CRFDontDelete\$name"
    }
}
```

Comment: OK - any thoughts on how to fix what I'm doing then?  You've only summarized what my code is doing.  I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the ID's and for each ID it goes through, find that ID's file name and use that.  For example, (making up numbers/names) -- file id 1234 is named test.zip and file id 4321 is named test2.zip.  I need to be able to go through all files found based on the JSON response I'm getting back and, for each ID it finds, use that ID in the download and then name the output file the name in the JSON under that ID.